# error: multiple definition of... when defining an extern variable in a third library

Tags: c++, libraries, extern

I have three libraries:

The first (Lib.h) declares a variable that will be defined elsewhere:

```cpp
extern int a;
```

The second one (Lib2.h) includes the third one:

```cpp
#include "Lib3.h"
```

The .cpp file of this library (Lib2.cpp) contains nothing besides this:

```cpp
#include "Lib2.h"
```

and the third (Lib3.h) finally contains the definition of the variable:

```cpp
int a;
```

The main program simply includes the first and second library:

```cpp
#include "Lib.h"
#include "Lib2.h"
```

When I compile the main program, I get the error mentioned.

What is the problem here?

Comment: You need to define the variable in a cpp file, not a header file.

Comment: Why is your variable in a header file?

Comment: So I should make a Lib3.cpp file and put the line in there?

Comment: Yep.  Unless you are dealing with templates, or you use the `inline` keyword, all definitions should be in a cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `int a;` exists in `Lib3.h`, then every translation unit that includes `Lib3.h` (directly or indirectly) will get its own copy of `a`, hence the error.  `a` needs to be declared in `Lib3.h` as `extern`, just like it is in `Lib.h`, and then the actual `int a;` variable needs to be defined in a `.cpp` file elsewhere (`Lib2.cpp` will suffice) so there is only 1 copy of `a` that all of the `extern`s refer to.